# Drag and drop not working on dynamic data

Tags: javascript

I am using redips plugin(http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/) for drag and drop. It is working on static data, but when data comes dynamic through java, the drag and drop stops. I am using the following functions to pick up data on drag and drop:

```
 droppedBefore: function() {}
            , finish: function() {}
```

The plugin is written on pure javascript, so jquery is not working otherwise we could use `$(document).live` for picking dynamic data
Please suggest something so that drag and drop can work on dynamic data also

Comment: can you check the console. what errors you are getting ?

Comment: Can you post more code? How are you adding the functions?

Comment: @ashok, there are no console errors

Comment: I think that you can try use html5 drag and drop. http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Answer (score 0):

Whenever table layout inside drag container is changed, then is needed to call **init()** or **initTables()** method. Please see example0 where new table is dynamically appended with jQuery.

http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/example00/index2.html

... and here is JavaScript code used in script.js file:

```
// new table using AJAX/jQuery to the drag container 
redips.load_table = function (button) {
    // parameter (example for ajax request)
    var id = 1;
    // disable button (it can be clicked only once)
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#c0c0c0';
    button.disabled = true;
    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: 'id=' + id,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            // load new table
            $('#load_content').html(result);
            // rescan tables
            REDIPS.drag.initTables();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

after post request change in table then call

REDIPS.drag.init();

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/recipe/sliderData",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataForSlider,
            success: function (data) { 
             //table change 

              REDIPS.drag.init();// 
            },
            error: function (data) {
              alert("Error")
            }
          });
```